# Proving $O(1,1)$ is diffeomorphic to the disjoint union of 4 copies of the real line.

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm trying to prove that the pseudo-orthogonal group $O(1,1)$ is diffeomorphic to the disjoint union of four copies of $\mathbb{R}$. Firstly I tried to solve the equation $AI_{p,q}A^T = I_{p,q}$ where $I_{p,q} = diag(\underbrace{1, \dots, 1}_{p},\underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{q})$ and $A \in O(p,q)$ . I obtained that each matrix in $O(p,q)$ is of the form 
$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
coshx & sinhx \\
sinhx & coshx \end{array} \right)
$, $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-coshx & sinhx \\
sinhx & -coshx \end{array} \right)
$, $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
coshx & sinhx \\
-sinhx & -coshx \end{array} \right)
$ or $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-coshx & sinhx \\
-sinhx & coshx \end{array} \right)
$. I'm struggling with what to do now. I think I want to show that each of these matrices are diffeomorphic to a copy of the real line but I'm not too sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Yes, that's what you want. There is an obvious diffeomorphism in each case, by construction.

Comment: So should I map the matrix $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
coshx & sinhx \\
sinhx & coshx \end{array} \right)
$ to $x$?

Comment: Well, it's easier to go the other way first; in the direction you suggest it's not obvious that the map is well-defined.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help.